# Extract string before certain character or without that character present

Tags: sql

I am using SQL Server 2016 and I am trying to extract the first set of numbers of a certain string. Here are some examples

```
12345
123456
12345-ks
12345-12
123456-ks
```

I want:

```
12345
123456
12345
12345
123456
```

I have tried `SUBSTRING(@str, 0, charindex('-', str@, 0)`. But that excludes any strings without '-'

I have also tried using a case statement to include those strings. But, I can't group by a case statement. Any thoughts?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: what did you mean by ` I can't group by a case statement`? You can! what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

I've used a case statement to return the whole value when the column does not constain -.

> ```
> create table strings ( s varchar(10));
> insert into strings values
> ('12345'),
> ('123456'),
> ('12345-ks'),
> ('12345-12'),
> ('123456-ks');
>
> select 
>   case when charindex('-',s,0) = 0
>   then  s
>   else SUBSTRING(s,0,
>           charindex('-', s, 0)
>           ) 
>   end as first_group
> from strings;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ci | first_group
> -: | :----------
>  0 | 12345      
>  0 | 123456     
>  6 | 12345      
>  6 | 12345      
>  7 | 123456
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=27620f72b23d0b62bfe677967c3d2bd1)*